# Is there a good open source abstract load balancing library for Java?

Tags: java, open-source, load-balancing

I'm looking for an open source library that will allow programmatic loadbalancing across a set of calls to nodes of arbitrary form - so no assumptions about HTTP or anything else, just a method call on an object.  Ideally it would provide the following functionality:

- Balances the load equally
- Retry on a different node if a call to a node throws an exception
- Move a node to a "broken" state if a call to it fails, and make no further calls to it
- Have a mechanism for doing background pings to all nodes (broken and active) that will restore broken ones to active state when they return and proactively move active ones to broken state if they fail

I feel this ought to exist already, but some googling has yet to find it.

Comment: This is usually done in hardware using F5 or Ace.

Comment: I don't think that's practical in this case - we are using an existing API that does a direct TCP/IP socket connection to a remote node and there is no F5 or ace.  There are multiple nodes, and we need to handle failover etc.  It seemed the simplest solution would be a software load balancer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using Apache Camel library. There is a flexible [load balancer](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) and the library have a vast variety of components so you don't stick to particular protocol or service implementation. With Camel [Bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) component you can load-balance even POJO method calls.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at JavaSpaces. The paradigm there is a simple queue. The least active processor is the most likely to take the next item on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can be interesting but it doesn't meet all your requirements: https://code.google.com/p/valogato/